# Link edit desactivado

Tags: soporte, ediciones

Parece que no puedo editar esta [respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3998/776) por estar el link desactivado. No es cuestión de falta de rep, ya que puedo editar otras preguntas o respuestas sin problema. ¿Será que está aún en la cola de *Low quality posts* (a la cual no tengo acceso, por eso pregunto)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's because there was a suggested edit in the queue, I've just approved the edition. Check if you can edit it now.

Comment: Indeed, I can edit it now. Thanks!